# Wrong grub2 prefix when booting over network

Tags: pxe-boot, dnsmasq, grub2

I have dnsmasq in proxy mode, serving pxe service and tftp server using this config:

```
port=0
log-dhcp
log-queries
log-facility=/var/log/dnsmasq.log
dhcp-range=192.168.0.0,proxy

enable-tftp
tftp-root=/tftp
pxe-service=x86-64_EFI,boot, grub/bootx64.efi
```

Using this configuration. Grub loads fine but has wrong prefix, net_default_server and pxe_default_server values. They are set to 192.168.0.1, which is IP adrress of router providing DHCP. When i manualy set prefix and root and run the `normal` command. The config loads and everything works fine.

I am using the [grubnetx64.efi.signed file provided by ubuntu](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/uefi/grub2-amd64/current/grubnetx64.efi.signed), with shim for secure boot.

How does grub determines the value for these variables?

Can i permanently change them?

Answer (score 1):

This is a long-known bug in Shim/Grub.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shim/+bug/1813541

It occurs in proxy-configurations, where DHCP<>PXE. The shim is TFTP-hardcoded to DHCP and ignores PXE-option "next-server". Since you need a (Microsoft) signed version, you are in the hands of Ubuntu or Debian. But for years now this remains unfixed.

Comment: If your TFTP content is static, you might consider to install an additional/duplicated TFTP service on your DHCP server as a possible work-around.

Comment: Unfortunetly i cannot change the DHCP server, thats why i went with the proxy option. I hope they fix it in the near future.